# How to install plugin for Etherpad Lite on Sandstorm?

Tags: node.js, etherpad, sandstorm.io

we're running a `Sandstorm` server, and we installed `Etherpad` through Sandstorm App Market.

Now we want to install plugins like to insert a image, but [the wiki page](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Available-Plugins) only describes steps on a standalone Etherpad server. On `Sandstorm` version I can't find the admin page or the etherpad-lite directory to `npm`.

[Etherpad Lite's github readme](https://github.com/kentonv/etherpad-lite) says it's possible to install plugins. Does anyone know the steps to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment the only way to add plugins to Etherpad on Sandstorm is to build the Sandstorm package from source. Here's the repo for the Sandstorm packaging:

https://github.com/kentonv/etherpad-lite

The reason for this is that Sandstorm's packaging and security model requires apps to be basically immutable. In the future we hope to extend Sandstorm to support a concept of "add-on packages", in which case Etherpad plugins could be introduced as additional packages, but currently there is no timeline for that.

If the plugins you'd like to have added would make sense to push to all Etherpad-on-Sandstorm users, then please feel free to file an issue on the github repo I linked above requesting that I add them. It's pretty easy for me to push a new package with added plugins.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm going to learn how to re-package an app :) I believe it's a better way in the future.

Comment: Syntax Highlighting plugin. For interleaving code with rich text like blog posts. As with Codepad everything is treated as code!